# Why does my page keep auto-refreshing?

Tags: html

I have a page with the following HTML.  It keeps refreshing, and I don't want it to.  Why is it doing that and how do I stop it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Yet another exif viewer from Phil Harvey's exiftool</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Yet another online exif viewer from Phil Harvey's exiftool. This is an online image metadata viewer">
  <meta name="keywords" content="EXIF,XMP,metadata,gif,jpg,adobe">
  <meta name="author" content="Guinsly Mond">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-filestyle.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 well">
     <h1>Upload your Image <small style="font-size:45%;">Please make sure that your file name is display in the input file</small></h1>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
    <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="file" data-buttonName="btn-primary" placeholder="imge">
    <div class="text-center">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sml" style="margin-top:10px;">
    </div>
  </form>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a meta tag on the page telling it to refresh every 10 seconds.  Remove the following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```